# Vue elements not being displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, materialize

I am trying to create Vue elements using `template` elements in the body of the HTML. It was working pretty well until I tried to use two of them together.

```
<template id="root-template">
  <div>
    <app-navbar targetId="#app-sidenav" />
    <app-header />
  </div>
</template>
```

For some reason, commenting out `app-navbar` causes `app-header` to be displayed, however if `app-navbar` is displayed, `app-header` is not being displayed at all! This one has completely stumped me.

```js
const Navbar = Vue.component("app-navbar", {
  name: "app-navbar",
  template: "#navbar-template",
  props: {
    targetId: {
      type: String,
      default: "#app-sidenav"
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.sidenav = M.Sidenav.init(document.querySelector(this.targetId));
  },
});

const Header = Vue.component("app-header", {
  name: "app-header",
  template: "#header-template"
});

const AppRoot = Vue.component("app-root", {
  template: "#root-template",
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Header
  },
});

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {},
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {}
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  render: h => h(AppRoot)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.2/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons&type=.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<ul class="sidenav" id="app-sidenav">
  <li><a href="#">Sass</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Components</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="app" />
<template id="navbar-template">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-target="app-sidenav" class="sidenav-trigger">
        <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
      </a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>
<template id="header-template">
  <div class="section no-pad-bot" id="index-banner">
    <div class="container">
      <br /><br />
      <h1 class="header center orange-text">Todos</h1>
      <div class="row center">
        <h5 class="header col s12 light">
          A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div class="row center">
        <a href="http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html" id="download-button"
          class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light orange">Get Started</a>
      </div>
      <br /><br />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<template id="root-template">
  <div>
    <app-navbar target-id="#app-sidenav" />
    <app-header />
  </div>
</template>
```

I've also turned this into a [Pen](https://codepen.io/ksefchik/pen/xxGGRXq?editors=1010). Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe try the VUE cli to build the standard VUE setup instead of this syntax. Also, are you importing the components properly? I'm not seeing that in data like in a normal VUE setup.

Comment: @CoderLee I need to use a single file setup. Components are created in place and assembled right in main script -- no need for CLI.

Comment: Why do you need a single file setup? That's an atypical approach, but explaining why will make it easier to help.

Comment: Because the device this is intended for has many functions and files on it already and does not need its source code further complicated by installing multiple bundled apps onto it's already complex folder hierarchy.

Comment: See my answer below, it's not reading your templates properly causing it to only evaluate the one component. The easy fix is to put the templates in the component functions. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use self-closing tags in regular HTML files.

If you change these lines of HTML:

```html
<app-navbar target-id="#app-sidenav" />
<app-header />
```

to these:

```html
<app-navbar target-id="#app-sidenav"></app-navbar>
<app-header></app-header>
```

it will work.

Comment: Good point, the self closing tags mess up the parsing. Good fix for a non-js solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should put the templates in the functions if you're going with a single file approach. See the below code for an example. The templates aren't parsing properly, because of the self closing syntax, and hence only displaying the one component. When you use template strings you can get the expected display from the templates how you have them now. Just put them inside the component function's `template:` like so:

```js
const Navbar = Vue.component("app-navbar", { 
    name: "app-navbar", 
    template: 
      `
       <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper container">
          <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
          <a href="#" data-target="app-sidenav" class="sidenav-trigger">
            <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
          </a>
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="#">Sass</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      `, 
    props: { 
      targetId: { 
        type: String, 
        default: "#app-sidenav" 
      } 
    },
    mounted() {
      this.sidenav = M.Sidenav.init(document.querySelector(this.targetId));
    },
});

const Header = Vue.component("app-header", {
  name: "app-header",
  template: 
    `
    <div class="section no-pad-bot" id="index-banner">
      <div class="container">
        <br /><br />
        <h1 class="header center orange-text">Todos</h1>
        <div class="row center">
          <h5 class="header col s12 light">
            A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="row center">
          <a href="http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html" id="download-button"
            class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light orange">Get Started</a>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
      </div>
    </div>
    `
});

const AppRoot = Vue.component("app-root", {
  template: 
    `
    <div>
      <!--   Comment out the navbar to see the header. expected behavior is that both ar displayed   -->
      <app-navbar target-id="#app-sidenav" />
      <app-header />
    </div>
    `,
  components: { Navbar, Header },
});

store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {},
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {}
});

app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  render: h => h(AppRoot)
});
```

Remove the templates in your code pen and add this to the JS to see it working. Alternatively you can use the closing tags syntax for your components, but it's more readable and intuitive to use self closing tags and separate your display bits into their functions instead of a large blob of `<template></template>` tags. Just my opinion of cleaner code, so feel free to use either approach as desired/needed.